# Mongodb aggregate match on dates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm running an aggregate query, and after a few projections, I end up with documents that look like

```
{ _id: 561bed08f8f068cd237a3dc1,
updateDate: Mon Oct 12 2015 11:25:28 GMT-0600 (MDT),
manager: 561bdd37f8f068cd237a3da2,
viewDate: Mon Oct 26 2015 09:02:57 GMT-0600 (MDT) }
```

Please note, those dates are the console formatted output, when inspected with mongohub, the dates look like `new Date(<timestamp>)`.

I want to match documents where the `updateDate` is greater than the `viewDate`, so I have this match:

```
$match: {
    updateDate: { "$gt": new Date("$viewDate") }
}
```

However, it returns documents such as the one above, the `updateDate` is on the 12th, and the `viewDate` is on the 26th.

I have tried a few variations, with and without the `new Date()` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `$match` operator here. You need to use the [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact) operator.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$redact": { 
        "$cond": [ 
           { "$gt": ["$updateDate", "$viewDate"] }, 
           "$$KEEP", 
           "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }}
])
```

Comment: This seems to work! Do you mind explaining `$$KEEP` and `$$PRUNE`?  I read the docs on them and they seem to conflict in their purpose.

Comment: `$$KEEP` to keep documents that match your criteria and `$$PRUNE` to discard documents that don't.